# How to understand the electric-field operator in quantum optics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, electric-fields, quantum-optics

I know the positive field operator $\mathbf{E}^{+}$ is actually an annihilation operator $a$ while the negative field $\mathbf{E}^{-}$ is a creation operator $a^{+}$.

I also learned that the absorption process can be represented as $\mathbf{E}^{-}\mathbf{E}^{+}$, which should be the number of photons $n$ accroding to the principle of ladder operator. Also, the emission is $\mathbf{E}^{+}\mathbf{E}^{-}$, whose eigenvalu however is $n+1$.

How to understand this extra 1 here? Why emitted number is $n+1$ rather than $n$? Is that 1 the vacuum field? But should the vacuum field cannot released through emission?

Answer (score 2):

The extra one simply reflects the commutation relationship $[a,\,a^\dagger] = \mathrm{id}$ of the quantum mechanical harmonic oscillator. If each annihilation operator in the expression for $E^+$ acts only on its corresponding mode, and likewise for the creation operators in $E^-$, then the action of $E^-\,E^+ -E^+\,E^-$ on a state involving only excitations in a given mode must be the same as the action of $[a,\,a^\dagger]$ on that state, *i.e.* the same as the action of the identity operator. So the two entities $E^-\,E^+$ and $E^+\,E^-$ have the same eigenvectors, and the eigenvalues differ by 1. It's exactly the same case with a simple harmonic oscillator. The number operator is $a^\dagger\,a$, and $a\,a^\dagger$ has the same eigenvectors, with eigenvalues $n+1$ rather than $n$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I want to know is the physical meaning of that $1$. I understand the commutation relationship has to be hold by the field operator. Is that $1$ represents the spontaneous emission process driven by the vacuum field?